# I can't boot Ubuntu after installing it

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (dual boot with Windows 10) on my second desktop following the same steps I did with the first one.

However, Windows is installed in a different hard drive. Before this installation I used an SSD (where Windows is installed) and an HD. I separated 300GB for Ubuntu, allocated the free space in a new partition in the HD, the same way as all guides.

After completing the installation and restarting the system, it booted back from the flash drive I used for installation and Ubuntu doesn't show up on the boot options.

In GParted, the partitions I used for installation are locked, meaning they're mounted:
[image: In GParted, the partitions I used for installation are locked, meaning they're mounted]

SSD with Windows installed:
[image: SSD with Windows installed]

I read that the Grub Menu should work if Ubuntu were installed in the same drive as Windows, but I don't know if it's true. I just want to be able to boot in my installation. Trying to boot from the HDD didn't work either.

Comment: Try to access UEFI boot menu and see if Ubuntu is there. Alternatively, run `efibootmgr` from Ubuntu USB and post results here ([edit] your question)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not in the UEFI boot menu. I ran `efibootmgr` and it returned "EFI variables are not supported on this system."
Some other things I did since I posted:
- Tried do disable Legacy mode, which returned: "The VBIOS of your discrete VGA card does not support UEFI GOP, so it can not support Ultra Fast Boot and CSM Disable."
- Read some guides to install ubuntu in Legacy mode (which seemed to me like the same process, except this time I created a boot partition.)
-The locked partitions in GParted are no longer a problem, I just had to "swapoff".

Comment: Also, trying to boot from the disk where Ubuntu is installed, it says there's no OS installed.